# How to create the custom authorize filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I  create my own authorize filter for the asp.net mvc controller?

I want to secure the controller actions that are releated to xo, what do I need to do for that?

Comment: `actions that are releated to xo`? I don't get it. What is `xo`?

Comment: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend AuthorizeAttribute and override AuthorizeCore, add in your own logic and return true or false.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var defaultResult = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        // custom logic

        return true; // or false
    }
}
```